# how to replace when drop and drag continer Js or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

[image]

I have  10 containers. for example ;
when I drag the first container and drop  onto eight container that replaces to eight to one

1.container -> drag drop -> 8.container then call function automatic 8.container -> drag drop -> 1.container . ' replacement contents of container

Comment: have you write code for it?

Comment: yes ı have  . take

Comment: where is it?, Edit the question

Comment: look comment pls

Comment: You have added your html code in answer section, you need to add it to question section

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
<div class="row cube">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
             1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
             2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
             3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
             4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
        6
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
            7
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
            8
        </div>
    </div> 
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
            9
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 kup">
        <div class="icerik">
            10
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```